# Aplicar una condición a una variable global

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Es posible aplicar condiciones al valor de una variable? En el código que sigue docHeight funciona si le doy un valor fijo dentro de mi código completo pero cuando introduzco éstas condiciones docHeight aparece con un valor indefinido.

```js
var docHeight=11000;

switch ($(".basic_unit").css("font-size")) {
case '2px' :
    docHeight =11000;
    break;

case '6px' :
    docHeight = 32500;
    break;

case '8px' :
    docHeight = 48500;
    break;
};
```

Comment: Tu código contiene errores: faltan `;` y hay un `==` donde debería haber un `=`. Además, no inicializas `docHeight` y no defines un valor por defecto en el switch-case, por lo que seguramente sea undefined si no se cumple alguna de las condiciones

Comment: Corregí los errores que me comentas @alvaromontoro y continúa sin funcionar, en lugar de cambiar el valor de la variable cuando cambia el tamaño de la fuente se mantiene en el valor que le di para inicializarla

Comment: @Ivansoler has verificado que valores se obtienen de : $(".basic_unit").css("font-size") ???

Comment: actualiza el código de la pregunta para enseñar más de lo que estás haciendo. Porque el switch funciona perfectamente bien. Como te decía @rnd en otra de tus preguntas: el verdadero problema es que no sabes cuál es el problema y tienes a la gente como patos mareados buscando soluciones a problemas faltos de información.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Es posible aplicar condiciones al valor de una variable?

**Sí, claro que es posible**. Otra cosa es que sea recomendado tener una variable global, pero esa ya es otra historia.

> En el código que sigue docHeight funciona si le doy un valor fijo dentro de mi código completo pero cuando introduzco éstas condiciones docHeight aparece con un valor indefinido.

El código de arriba es un switch-case con varios valores: 2px, 6px y 8px, en el que no se define un valor por defecto (usando `default`) **si no es ninguno de los valores disponibles, entonces docHeight será <strike>undefined como espeficicas en la pregunta</strike> 11000** que es el valor al que se inicializa, porque no se ha definido un caso para el `default`.

Como puedes ver en este [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wshvjs6w/2/), no es un error de JavaScript, ocurre así porque te estás dejando casos sin definir y no has definido un caso por defecto usando el `default`.

Comment: Muchas gracias alvaro tu información ha sido muy valiosa pero aún así continúa sin funcionar.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no funciona?

Comment: Lo había entendido mal, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Me parece qie simplemente no se estan obteniendo los casos definidos en el switch(),  2px, 6px u 8px, por esa razón no cambia el valor de tu variable docHeight.

agrega un alert para verificar en modo de prueba si se obtiene alguno de los valores definidos en el switch():

```
alert($(".basic_unit").css("font-size"));
```

puedes agregar un caso default como, para no obtener un valor indefinido:

```
switch ($(".basic_unit").css("font-size")) {
case '2px' :
    docHeight =11000;
    break;

case '6px' :
    docHeight = 32500;
    break;

case '8px' :
    docHeight = 48500;
    break;

default:
docHeight = 11000;
    break;

};
```

Comment: Hola Elena he hecho lo que dices y estos valores sí que se obtienen.

Comment: si en determinado momento cambiaran obtendrias un valor indefinido, te recomiendo agregar un default: .